# 'No suitable driver found' in Grails 2.3.0

Tags: grails

I have a brand new Grails 2.3.0 app, completely unconfigured—just out of the box settings after running `grails create-app`. I've found that `groovy.sql.Sql` code doesn't seem to work at all, and always triggers the following sql error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found forjdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000
```

Here's an example of code that causes the `No suitable driver found` error, I've just thrown it in `BootStrap.groovy`. Again, this is the only piece of code added to a brand new app.

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

class BootStrap {

    def grailsApplication

    def init = { servletContext ->

        try  {
            def sql = Sql.newInstance(grailsApplication.config.dataSource.url, grailsApplication.config.dataSource.username, grailsApplication.config.dataSource.password, grailsApplication.config.dataSource.driverClassName)
            sql.execute("create table newtable")
        }
        catch(java.sql.SQLException ex) {
            throw ex
        }

    }

    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

I think I have tracked down the issue to the following default `grails.project.fork` settings. If I comment them out, everything works fine and the table is created successfully:

```
grails.project.fork = [
    // configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version forked compilation is required
    //  compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],

    // configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
    test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
    // configure settings for the run-app JVM
    run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the run-war JVM
    war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the Console UI JVM
    console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]
```

Does the forked jvm block groovy sql class connectivity? I can't seem to figure out what's going on here.

Comment: does it work with the hibernate 3 plugin?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work with hibernate 3 either. Seems to be solely related to the forked jvm settings.

Comment: What do you mean by _"do anything with sql in the unit test"_?

Comment: Basically anytime the `groovy.sql.Sql` class is used. I've edited the question with an example test that triggers the error.

Comment: The issue is more general than I thought—I'm revising the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works if you inject the datasource:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

class BootStrap {

    def dataSource

    def init = { servletContext ->
        def sql = Sql.newInstance( dataSource )
        sql.execute( 'create table newtable' )
    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

It's injected into integration tests too:

```
package test

import spock.lang.*

class TestSpec extends Specification {

    def dataSource

    def setup() { }
    def cleanup() { }

    void "test dataSource injection"() {
        expect:
            dataSource != null
    }
}
```

passes when run with `grails test-app :integration`

Comment: Haha, good point.  Why would you *not* just inject the dataSource.

Comment: Thanks for stating the obvious! Can't believe I missed that...won't inject into a unit test like I originally needed but I probably shouldn't test db related activities in a unit test anyway.